# Photo taken by app not save in gallery

Tags: android, android-camera

I have a problem with save photo, in app directory (like example whatsapp) when take a picture directly on my app.

In my **Manifest** I have set these permits:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.myapp.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:readPermission="com.myapp.READ">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
    </provider>

</application>
```

In my activity I have:

```
public void showCamera(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {

            }

            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.myapp.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);

                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);

                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
                galleryAddPic();
            }
        }
    }

    String mCurrentPhotoPath;


    private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

And in my filePath resource:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.myapp/files/Pictures" />
```

It open camera, it take a picture and return on my activity, but I can not find it anywhere, so seem that not save a photo.

Answer (score 1):

if everything working right then put galleryAddPic() method in onActivityResult where you collect the captured picture.

Answer (score 0):

> I can not find it anywhere

You did not indicate how you are looking for it. Use `adb shell` to get a filesystem-level look at what is on your device or emulator.

Right now, your `ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE` will not work, as you are using an invalid path. A filesystem path does not begin with `file:`. I recommend getting rid of `mCurrentPhotoPath` entirely and hold onto the file returned by `createImageFile()` instead, using that with your `ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE` request (or, use `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()` instead of `ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE`).

Also, as Hardik notes, you are calling `galleryAddPic()` too soon. Wait until the picture is captured, by calling `galleryAddPic()` in `onActivityResult()`. While the file should exist at the point when you are calling `galleryAddPic()` now, it will not have the correct details (e.g., file size). This may confuse the user. You are better off waiting until the picture is ready, then ask for it to be indexed.

Comment: Ok, I put my `galleryAddPic()` on Override of `onActivityResult`, but nothing is changed.
I have use file that returned from `CreateImageFile()` and in `galleryAddPic()` I have `Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);`
May can be a problem with sendBroadcast?

Comment: @LorenzoBerti: "May can be a problem with sendBroadcast?" -- use `adb shell` to look to see if the image exists where you are asking for it to be saved. If the full photo is there, then something is wrong with the media-scanning logic. If the file is there but it is empty, then something is wrong with the image-capture logic (`createTempFile()` would have created an empty file). If the file is not there, then none of your code is being run.

Comment: Thankyou, I see photo in Android/data/com.myapp/files/Pictures after reboot, but not in gallery, How can I refresh media and put this in gallery?

Comment: @LorenzoBerti: "How can I refresh media and put this in gallery?" -- personally, I use `MediaScannerConnection` and its static `scanFile()` method. In theory, your `ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE` approach should work, though I have not used it. Also, to an extent, it depends on the behavior of the "gallery", which may or may not be using `MediaStore` to find photos to show.